# 18.04 Full screen recordings when trying to record w/OBS turn screen black

Tags: 18.04, screen, obs-studio

This problem is new for me and I'm new to Linux. I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. My laptop has 12gb of RAM, Corei5 8th gen, 1tb hard disk and only has ubuntu. It has Nvidia MX130 (low leve) and Intel Graphics HD 620.

So, when I try to use Open Broadcaster Studio to record my screen (not a window) only I can see the cursor and no more. In the same way, in the browser, when I try to share my screen with Google Meet again I can see only the cursor and no more. Everything is black.

I hoping you can help me and regards from Colombia.

Image: [My system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8syW8.png)

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive about your setup? Laptop or Desktop? Multiple monitors? Graphics Card? If yes have you installed the drivers?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) ? Are you using the low latency kernel? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Ok, I'm ready. You can see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a laptop. Only a monitor. It has 2 graphics cards. Nvidia And Intel Graphics. So, I put 5 images and you can see this. Fourth image is a full screen and fiveth image is only a window.
[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LssOV.png)
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lnt0.png)
[Img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhG68.png)
[Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59fdW.png)
[Image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbEY9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Good night people, I'm here because I found a solution to my problem.

So, I installed an Nvidia controller from software and updates. So, I was starting a session with ubuntu Wayland and not with ubuntu only. I started with ubuntu only and I can record my full screen without anything problem.

However, when I go back to the ubuntu Wayland, I have that problem, but it doesn't matter. I can record my screen! So, at the top right of my screen, it looks like there is a warning, why? Does the Nvidia controller have a problem?

See:
[problem captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEda7.png)